# Refresh dashboard with action or URL

Tags: apex, visualforce, reporting, dashboard

Is there a way I can initiate a dashboard refresh from a VF page remotely?

Is there an action or a URL I can use to refresh a specified dashboard?

I want to recreate the refresh dashboard button on my VF page. I have seen the schedule refresh option but I am looking for more control for the user to refresh the dashboard on demand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Salesforce allows you to do this through the [Reports and Dashboards REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_dashboard_refresh.htm)

If you make an http PUT request to: *BaseURL*/services/data/v31.0/analytics/dashboards/*DashboardID* and set the session id in the request header, it will refresh the dashboard for you.

In a Visualforce page, you could add a method to your controller similar to the following:

```
public void refreshDashboard(){
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
    req.setMethod('PUT');
    req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v35.0/analytics/dashboards/01Z90000000A7Nx');

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't through salesforce or a url param, but you could make a quick java(or language of choice) program to login and do it with a library like phantomjs.