# Is there any way to schedule dashboard refresh at schedule time

Tags: apex, visualforce, scheduled-apex, scheduled

I am trying to implement a process which can help me in refreshing the dashboard after one hour.

I have tried using salesforce process builder but that too depends on having an activity.Please do suggest if there is any way within salesforce through which we can implement the same.

Comment: You can make a REST call that will refresh the dashboard. Check out this answer: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108138/refresh-dashboard-with-action-or-url

Comment: @cricketlang How to schedule it.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like [@cricketlang](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/12582/cricketlang) has commented about another answer on how to to cause the dashboard to refresh via a REST call made in Apex.

Now you just need to schedule some apex to run at the required time. See [Apex Scheduler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm). Note that because you want to make a callout from the scheduled Apex you should make the actual REST call in an Apex method annotated with `@future(callout=true)`. Then call this future method from the scheduled classes execute method.

Putting it all together, it would look something like this (untested):

```
global class DelayedDashboardRefresh implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        refreshDashboard('01Z90000000A7Nx');
    }

    @future(callout=true)
    public void refreshDashboard(Id dashboardId){
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
        req.setMethod('PUT');
        req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v35.0/analytics/dashboards/' + dashboardId);

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    }

}
```

Then schedule it to run in one hour:

```
DelayedDashboardRefresh m = new DelayedDashboardRefresh();
Datetime dt = Datetime.now().addHours(1);
String timeForScheduler = dt.format('s m H d M \'?\' yyyy');
String jobID = system.schedule('Delayed Dashboard Refresh', timeForScheduler, m);
```

Comment: I think that without various hacks to get sessionId from a VF page, that you need to be at V44.0 to use this as `getSessionId()` would otherwise return null  in an async transaction.